# .Net Frameworks 4.0 application crashed on Windows XP SP3?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

I wrote an application on Visual Studio 2012 installed on Windows 7.

I configured all projects using .Net Framework 4.0.

When I deploy this app, It worked fine on Windows 7, Windows Vista, but it crashed on Windows XP SP3. Although on Windows XP SP3 installed .Net Framework 4.0 and Redistribute C++ 2012 (see below picture). I'm using Windows XP SP3 in Virtual Machine.
 [image]

And the some below pictures was snapshot from crash window message.
[image]
[image]
[image]

And this is the content of logs file

```
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="MysticServer.exe" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="avcodec-54.dll" SIZE="15301120" CHECKSUM="0xE0CBE003" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xEA64D2" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="avdevice-54.dll" SIZE="1190912" CHECKSUM="0xDFAC02B9" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x12AFC9" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="avfilter-3.dll" SIZE="1648128" CHECKSUM="0x2C93E410" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x19B9C6" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="avformat-54.dll" SIZE="3087872" CHECKSUM="0xB58C6CC2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x2FE1E9" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="avutil-52.dll" SIZE="226304" CHECKSUM="0xFA1B5BD5" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x41A70" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Common.dll" SIZE="103936" CHECKSUM="0x7C557FD9" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:28:58" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:28:58" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="CPPWrapper.dll" SIZE="207872" CHECKSUM="0xF0BC503" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:30:06" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:30:06" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="CSUtilityAPI.dll" SIZE="28672" CHECKSUM="0xBC6004F3" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="CSUtilityAPI" PRODUCT_NAME="CSUtilityAPI" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="CSUtilityAPI.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="CSUtilityAPI.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright ©  2013" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:28:46" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:28:46" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="CustomControls.dll" SIZE="35328" CHECKSUM="0x87A11F97" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="CustomControls" PRODUCT_NAME="CustomControls" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="CustomControls.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="CustomControls.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright ©  2008" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="07/07/2012 08:30:09" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/07/2012 08:30:09" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="DVRServerCore.dll" SIZE="443904" CHECKSUM="0xF4B4CFB2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:30:00" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:30:00" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="DVRSupervisorCore.dll" SIZE="143360" CHECKSUM="0xCA1936F6" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:34:16" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:34:16" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="DVRSupervisorCSUtility.dll" SIZE="4608" CHECKSUM="0xF9547A91" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="CSUtility" PRODUCT_NAME="CSUtility" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="DVRSupervisorCSUtility.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="DVRSupervisorCSUtility.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright ©  2013" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:34:10" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:34:10" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="DVRSupervisorWrapper.dll" SIZE="110592" CHECKSUM="0xC1332AE0" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:34:20" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:34:20" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="IPCameraAxisAPI.dll" SIZE="166400" CHECKSUM="0xDCE4A3C5" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:29:05" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:29:05" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="IPCameraPanasonicAPI.dll" SIZE="48128" CHECKSUM="0x1AA01C27" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:29:04" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:29:04" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="LOVADKeyRegistry.exe" SIZE="111616" CHECKSUM="0xA433FB78" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="LOVADKeyRegistry" COMPANY_NAME="LOVAD" PRODUCT_NAME="LOVADKeyRegistry" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="LOVADKeyRegistry.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="LOVADKeyRegistry.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © LOVAD 2013" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:34:57" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:34:57" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="LOVADSupervisor.exe" SIZE="29184" CHECKSUM="0x968B222A" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="LOVADSupervisor" COMPANY_NAME="LOVAD" PRODUCT_NAME="LOVADSupervisor" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="LOVADSupervisor.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="LOVADSupervisor.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © LOVAD 2013" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:34:22" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:34:22" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="ManagedType.dll" SIZE="350208" CHECKSUM="0x39D37CD9" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:29:15" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:29:15" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.dll" SIZE="122880" CHECKSUM="0xA780B546" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Microsoft.Expression.Drawing" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft.Expression.Drawing" FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x29125" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:12:07" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:12:07" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="MotionDetection.dll" SIZE="185856" CHECKSUM="0x36D07DD2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:29:27" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:29:27" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="MysticServer.exe" SIZE="5214208" CHECKSUM="0xA5259053" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="MysticServer" COMPANY_NAME="LOVAD" PRODUCT_NAME="MysticServer" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="MysticServer.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="MysticServer.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © LOVAD 2013" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:30:12" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:30:12" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="postproc-52.dll" SIZE="196608" CHECKSUM="0xB43CC727" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x360CD" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="ServerCommunication.dll" SIZE="113664" CHECKSUM="0x35080169" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:29:27" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2014 05:29:27" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="swresample-0.dll" SIZE="287744" CHECKSUM="0xBECA4CF" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x55809" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="swscale-2.dll" SIZE="357888" CHECKSUM="0x473FFCF" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x6610A" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/27/2013 05:02:25" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll" SIZE="4051968" CHECKSUM="0x105C60C2" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Telerik.Windows.Controls" COMPANY_NAME="Telerik" PRODUCT_NAME="RadControls for WPF" FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Telerik 2002-2012" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x3E514C" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:21:54" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:21:54" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.dll" SIZE="858112" CHECKSUM="0xFEA2AA8D" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking" COMPANY_NAME="Telerik" PRODUCT_NAME="RadControls for WPF" FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Telerik 2002-2012" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xE117D" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:24:07" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:24:07" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.ImageEditor.dll" SIZE="579584" CHECKSUM="0x35BDD7DA" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Telerik.Windows.Controls.ImageEditor" PRODUCT_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.ImageEditor" FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.ImageEditor.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.ImageEditor.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Telerik 2002-2012" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x99431" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:28:20" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:28:20" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.dll" SIZE="3084800" CHECKSUM="0xAD2A38B" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input" PRODUCT_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input" FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Telerik 2002-2012" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x2FCC42" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:23:34" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:23:34" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.dll" SIZE="3992576" CHECKSUM="0x6ABEB2F0" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation" PRODUCT_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation" FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Telerik 2002-2012" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x3D40F4" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:22:56" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:22:56" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView.dll" SIZE="1730048" CHECKSUM="0xAE32816E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView" COMPANY_NAME="Telerik" PRODUCT_NAME="RadControls for WPF" FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Telerik 2002-2012" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1AD0E7" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:26:01" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:26:01" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI.dll" SIZE="1586688" CHECKSUM="0x729414BA" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI" COMPANY_NAME="Telerik" PRODUCT_NAME="RadControls for WPF" FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Telerik 2002-2012" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x184D10" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:29:04" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:29:04" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Telerik.Windows.Data.dll" SIZE="453632" CHECKSUM="0x46889A34" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Telerik.Windows.Data" PRODUCT_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Data" FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Telerik.Windows.Data.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Data.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Telerik 2002-2012" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x7DAD4" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:22:10" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:22:10" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Telerik.Windows.Documents.dll" SIZE="2217984" CHECKSUM="0x46F68F9A" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Telerik.Windows.Documents" COMPANY_NAME="Telerik" PRODUCT_NAME="RadControls for WPF" FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Telerik.Windows.Documents.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Telerik.Windows.Documents.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Telerik 2002-2012" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x22B993" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2012.3.1017.40" LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:28:38" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/17/2012 08:28:38" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="WpfAnimatedGif.dll" SIZE="36352" CHECKSUM="0xBA929349" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.4.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.4.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.4.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="WpfAnimatedGif" COMPANY_NAME="Thomas Levesque" PRODUCT_NAME="WpfAnimatedGif" FILE_VERSION="1.4.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="WpfAnimatedGif.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="WpfAnimatedGif.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright ©  2012" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.4.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.4.0.0" LINK_DATE="02/14/2013 14:17:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/14/2013 14:17:25" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="WPFToolkit.dll" SIZE="467288" CHECKSUM="0x26A1886A" BIN_FILE_VERSION="3.5.50211.1" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="3.5.50211.1" PRODUCT_VERSION="3.5.50211.1" FILE_DESCRIPTION="WPF Toolkit" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corp." PRODUCT_NAME="WPF Toolkit" FILE_VERSION="3.5.50211.1" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="WPFToolkit.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="WPFToolkit.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2010 Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x73E93" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="3.5.50211.1" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="3.5.50211.1" LINK_DATE="03/02/2010 09:10:20" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/02/2010 09:10:20" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll" SIZE="669184" CHECKSUM="0x399BB4B0" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.9.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.9.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.9.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit" COMPANY_NAME="Xceed Software Inc." PRODUCT_NAME="Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit" FILE_VERSION="1.9.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Xceed Software Inc. 2010-2012" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xACF86" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.9.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.9.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2013 13:38:31" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2013 13:38:31" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="KERNEL32.dll" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="991744" CHECKSUM="0x5ACBF35E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293 (xpsp_sp3_qfe.121001-1624)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xFBE8A" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" LINK_DATE="10/03/2012 04:57:29" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/03/2012 04:57:29" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="991744" CHECKSUM="0x5ACBF35E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293 (xpsp_sp3_qfe.121001-1624)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xFBE8A" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" LINK_DATE="10/03/2012 04:57:29" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/03/2012 04:57:29" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>
```

Someone can help me?

Many Thanks,

T&T

Comment: Same problem for me, but I haven't written application. I am running EleksCAM in win XP SP3

Answer (score 1):

Check your application not ref exclude dll. And your appication is 32bit or 64bit ?

If is 64bit application  try convert to 32bit ,And run again .

Btw. Some you ref extension dll is 64bit , maybe can't run in XP.

Because XP is 32bit System

Comment: Thanks for your help! My Application is 32Bit, but How do you know that my app ref some 64bit dll? Please show me those 64bits dll?